# Using React and Redux I want to send data to my JSON file when I click the button

Tags: reactjs, json, redux

When I click the heart button, I want the information on the card to be saved in the json file. I'm new to React and Redux Js and a bit of a novice. I hope I explained correctly.

//This is my Json data.

```
{
            "news" : [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title" : " Title", 
                    "description" : " Description Text", 
                    "author" : " News",
                    "publishedAt" : "2022-04-23T07:45:02Z",
                    "url" : "https://twitter.com",
                    "urlToImage" : "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/96/b3/32/96b332085dc6e65245531e17f9fccb85.png"
                },
               "id": 2,
                    "title" : " Title", 
                    "description" : " Description Text", 
                    "author" : " News",
                    "publishedAt" : "2022-04-23T07:45:02Z",
                    "url" : "https://twitter.com",
                    "urlToImage" : "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/96/b3/32/96b332085dc6e65245531e17f9fccb85.png"
                }
            ]
        }
```

// This is APİ folder

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL : 'http://localhost:3002/'
})
```

// This is my Action

```
export const fetchRecorded = () => async dispatch =>{

const response = await recordedNews.get('news')

dispatch({type : 'FETCH_RECORDED', payload : response.data})
}
```

// This is my Reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action){
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_RECORDED':
            return action.payload;
            default:
                return state;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB6UC.png)

Comment: It’s not clear what the specific issue is. Are you asking how to write to a file in NodeJS?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. When I click the heart button, I want to print the data written on the card to my JSON file. I hope I was able to explain.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What is your store supposed to hold?
How do you dispatch the action?
Do you use selector to access store?

I can see that you initialize it with an empty array here's an example of what it could look like with some typing (typescript in this case)

```js
type RecordState = {
    records: RecordData[]
}

const initialState: RecordState = {
    records: []
};

export default function(state: RecordState = initialState, action: PayloadAction<any>){
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'FETCH_RECORDED':
            return reduceFetchRecords(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function reduceFetchRecords(state: RecordState, action: PayloadAction<RecordData[]>) {
    state.records = action.payload;
    return state;
}
```